# grails fail generated war (assets)

Tags: grails, deployment, war

i have a strange error when i generate war with *grails war* commande

> ```
> | Processing File 53 of 1214 - yuiApplication/dial/assets/dial-core.css.
> | Error WAR packaging error: /Users/sovlin/IdeaProjects/revelido/grails-app/assets/javascripts/yuiApplication/dial/assets (Is a directory)
> ```

I don't understand why this folder make problem. I check it but nothing of suspect.
I test *clean-clean* without success.
The *run-app* commande working.

Error with StackTrace

> war --stacktrace | Processing File 53 of 1214 -
>   yuiApplication/dial/assets/dial-core.css. | Error WAR packaging error:
>   /Users/sovlin/IdeaProjects/revelido/grails-app/assets/javascripts/yuiApplication/dial/assets
>   (Is a directory) | Error Error running script war --stacktrace:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.ScriptExitException (NOTE: Stack trace
>   has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.ScriptExitException
>           at _GrailsWar$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsWar.groovy:43)
>           at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
>           at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
>           at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
>           at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
>           at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
>           at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
>           at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
>           at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processClosure(GantMetaClass.java:81)
>           at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processArgument(GantMetaClass.java:95)
>           at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:128)
>           at War$_run_closure1.doCall(War.groovy:38)
>           at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
>           at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
>           at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
>           at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
>           at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
>           at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
>           at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
>           at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
>           at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
>           at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
>           at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
>           at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
>           at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
>           at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
>           at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
>           at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
>           at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
>           at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
>           at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590) | Error Error running script war --stacktrace:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.ScriptExitException

Here my plugin configuration

```
asset-pipeline      2.0.17           --  Asset Pipeline Plugin
cache               1.1.8            --  Cache Plugin
database-migration  1.4.0            --  Grails Database Migration Plugin
hibernate4          4.3.6.1          --  Hibernate 4 for Grails
jquery              1.11.1           --  jQuery for Grails
scaffolding         2.1.2            --  Grails Scaffolding Plugin
spring-security-core2.0-RC4          --  Spring Security Core Plugin
tomcat              8.0.15           --  Apache Tomcat plugin
webxml              1.4.1            --  WebXmlConfig
```

Thanks you for your help

Comment: Is it possible that you  have a `= require something` in one of your assets where `something` is in fact a folder and not a file (perhaps somewhere where you really wanted to put `require_tree`)? Or, guessing from the error report, that you are including a background image or something similar that is really a folder (perhaps you forgot to add `background.jpg`) somewhere? Do you have any Javascript errors in your console complaining about missing files if you open the site in dev mode?

Comment: thx for your answer but i not issus when my app running on the web browser. I can run it with **run-app** command but i can generate the war for product deployment.

Comment: I suggest you start removing plugins from the application like asset-pipeline, does it then build war without that plugin? You could also try creating a new empty grails app and slowly adding back in your application code to the empty project, building war each time you add to find the specific code that is causing it to fail.

Comment: @fourgablesguy I test your solution but unfortunately it's not work. I make an issue https://github.com/bertramdev/asset-pipeline/issues/185#issuecomment-66533015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It definitely has to do with a folder that is named as if it was a file that needs processing. Asset-Pipeline however should be correcting for this and I have modded core to ensure a check and make sure File is not a Directory. This is released in 2.0.18